# Why is AndroidStudio crashing on startup after Markdown Plugin install?

Tags: android, markdown, android-studio-4.0

Installing a new plugin caused some conflicts with an existing one. After restarting AndroidStudio it just crashes. I figured out a solution and thought I share it here.

Answer (score 1):

Because I had a weird problem with conflicting Plugins I thought I would share my experience on how to fix the problem, at least for me and hopefully for others.

I installed a new plugin called "Markdown Navigator Enhanced" by vladsch (v3.0.197.72) while having the JetBrains Markdown plugin still enabled. I thought I try something new but it seems that there is a conflict between the both plugins which caused a mess. After restarting, AndroidStudio crashed and closed immediately.

[image]

Because AndroidStudio crashed ungracefully I had no way to disable the plugin I just installed so I had to figure something out.

After looking for solutions on the web and not finding anything relevant I thought I give it a try myself.

I figured I had to disable at least the plugin manager or something along the line so I can at least enter AS and disable the plugin I just installed.

Actually it's an easy fix but it took me a while figuring out how to do it. Here are the steps for **MAC**

1. Enter the following directory `/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio4.0/marketplace/lib/boot/`
2. delete/move the file `marketplace-bootstrap.jar` **DON'T DELETE IT PERMANENTLY, only move it to the trash or some other folder**
3. Startup AndroidStudio and you should get the following Dialog
   [image]
4. Select `Use Markdown by JetBrains` for now, `Enable and Restart`
5. AS should open up. Make sure the plugin `Markdown Navigator Enhanced` is disabled.
   [image]
6. Close AndroidStudio --> Return the file `marketplace-bootstrap.jar` to his folder
7. Start Android Studio and you should now be able to use it as usual.

That's it, I hope I could help someone.